# Why doesn't cmd+tab bring non-fullscreen applications into focus when I'm on a fullsceen virtual desktop?

Tags: macos, applications, desktop

I use my laptop screen, two external screens, and a total of about 5 or 6 virtual desktops at any given time (usually full-screen applications). I've noticed that I can't cmd+tab to an application that isn't on the desktop I'm actively viewing, *if the application isn't also in a full-screen desktop*.

An example of this for me is Skype - I don't keep it maximized. When I'm on a virtual desktop and try to Cmd+Tab to Skype, it doesn't take me to that application. If I click it in the launcher, it pops up just fine (presumably because the launch only shows up on Desktop 1, so I have to swipe over to that Desktop to even click it!).

Any remedies would be super helpful.

Comment: Do you mean maximised, or full-screen?

Comment: Sorry, Full-screen